# Out of line definition of PostOrder c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Does anyone know why do I get out of line definition at bst_node* node?
They say that it does not match any declaration in bst

```
template<class T>
void bst<T>::postOrder(void(*func)(const T &func), bst_node<T>* node) {
    if (node == nullptr)
        return;

    /* first recur on left child */
    postOrder(func,node->left);
    /* now recur on right child */
    postOrder(func, node->right);
    /* then print the data of node */
    func(node->value);
}
```

Comment: They could be right for all we know. How are we supposed to tell?

Comment: can you explain where the problem is coming from ?

Comment: The error says that the function definition doesn't match any declaration in `class bst<T>`.  Since we can't see `class bst<T>`, I believe the compiler.

Comment: I believe it comes from the fact that you don't have a declaration in `bst` that matches the signature of `bst<T>::postOrder`, but it's really hard to be sure.